# Android: FacebookOperationCanceledException when tapping outside the dialog

Tags: android, facebook

i am developing an Android app which accesses FB account. I use FB-SDK 3 for this.

When needed, the SDK displays its webview to ask for the FB email and password or displays the native FB app if present. This can take up to 2 seconds, an indeterminate progress dialog is shown in the meantime.

My problem is: if the user taps OUTSIDE that indeterminate progress dialog, the whole thing is canceled, the SessionStatusCallback.call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) callback is called with an com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: User canceled log in. Same as if the user had pressed the back button to cancel it.

How can I prevent this outside tap way of cancellation?

Apart from that cancellation everything works well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution.

Debugged into the FB-SDK, there is a spinner in the webdialog.

I had to call spinner.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); on it after created.

I would appreciate comments about this solution from anyone.